# JSP fails with pagecontext cannot be resolved when accessing pageContext in a scriptlet contained in a taglib in JBoss

Tags: jsp, jboss, taglib, scriptlet

I have a JEE application that was deployed on Websphere and I'm migrating it to JBoss.

Some JSPs use a custom tablig where the pageContext is accessed to check and store variables.

Having a simple JSP like...

`<%= pageContext %>`

... it works fine.

However, when the same thing is inside my taglib if fails with pageContext cannot be resolved

Custom taglib:

```
<%@tag body-content="scriptless" description="xxx"%>
<%=pageContext %>
```

JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"  isErrorPage="false"%>

<xxx:mytag/>
```

Oddly enough, if the taglib is :

```
<%@tag body-content="scriptless" description="xxx"%>
${pageContext}
```

... it works, showing `org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspContextWrapper@xxx`:

How can I make it work with usual scriptlets?

Comment: First thing to check is that you are not bundling and JSP/Servlet related JARs in the deployed WAR. These should be provided by the app server/servlet container.

Comment: Already checked, those dependencies are provided.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, `pageContext` is not available inside a TagLib's scriptlet. However `jspContext`, which is `PageContext`'s parent class is, so that workaround fixed it for me:

```
<%@tag body-content="scriptless" description="xxx"%>
<%=jspContext %>
```